# Why is OpenCV Gpu module performing faster than VisionWorks?

Tags: opencv, nvidia, openvx

I have tried several functions of OpenCv gpu module and compared the same behavior with visionWorks immediate code. And surprisingly, it all circumstances the OpenCv Gpu Module is performing *significantly* faster than VisionWorks.

e-g 
a Gaussian pyramid of level 4 implemented manually using opencv

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>


#include <stdio.h>
#include <queue>
/* OPENCV RELATED */
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/util.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/warpers.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/warpers.hpp"
#include <opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp>  

#include "opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/autocalib.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/blenders.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/camera.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/exposure_compensate.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/matchers.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/motion_estimators.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/seam_finders.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/util.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/warpers.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/warpers.hpp"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

using namespace gpu;
using namespace cv::detail;


int main()
{
    Mat m = imread("br1.png");

    GpuMat d_m  = GpuMat (m);
    GpuMat d_m2;
    GpuMat l1,l2,l3,l4;
    int iter = 100;
    int64 e = getTickCount();
    float sum = 0;

    sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < iter;  i++)
    {
        e = getTickCount();
        gpu::pyrDown(d_m,l1);
        gpu::pyrDown(l1,l2);
        gpu::pyrDown(l2,l3);
        gpu::pyrDown(l3,l4);
        sum+= (getTickCount() - e) / getTickFrequency(); 
    }

    cout <<"Time taken by Gussian Pyramid Level 4 \t\t\t"<<sum/iter<<" sec"<<endl;

    //imwrite("cv_res.jpg",res);
    return 0;
}
```

takes 2.5 ms on average for 100 iterations. Whereas, VisionWorks

```
    #include <VX/vx.h>
#include <VX/vxu.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>


#include <stdio.h>
#include <queue>
/* OPENCV RELATED */
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/util.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/warpers.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/warpers.hpp"
#include <opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp>  

#include "opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/autocalib.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/blenders.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/camera.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/exposure_compensate.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/matchers.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/motion_estimators.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/seam_finders.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/util.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/warpers.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/warpers.hpp"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

using namespace gpu;
using namespace cv::detail;



vx_image createImageFromMat(vx_context& context, cv::Mat& mat);


vx_status createMatFromImage(vx_image& image, cv::Mat& mat);


/* Entry point. */
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{

    Mat cv_src1 = imread("br1.png", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
  int width = 1280;
  int height = 720;

  int half_width = width/2;
  int half_height = height/2;
    Mat dstMat(cv_src1.size(), cv_src1.type());
  Mat half_dstMat(Size(width/16,height/16),cv_src1.type());

  /* Image data. */


    if (cv_src1.empty() )
    {
        std::cerr << "Can't load input images" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }


  /* Create our context. */
  vx_context context = vxCreateContext();

  /* Image to process. */
  vx_image image = createImageFromMat(context, cv_src1);
   //NVXIO_CHECK_REFERENCE(image);

  /* Intermediate images. */
  vx_image dx = vxCreateImage(context, width, height, VX_DF_IMAGE_S16);
  vx_image dy = vxCreateImage(context, width, height, VX_DF_IMAGE_S16);
  vx_image mag = vxCreateImage(context, width, height, VX_DF_IMAGE_S16);
  vx_image half_image = vxCreateImage(context, half_width, half_height,  VX_DF_IMAGE_U8);
  vx_image half_image_2 = vxCreateImage(context, half_width/2, half_height/2,  VX_DF_IMAGE_U8);
  vx_image half_image_3 = vxCreateImage(context, half_width/4, half_height/4,  VX_DF_IMAGE_U8);
  vx_image half_image_4 = vxCreateImage(context, half_width/8, half_height/8,  VX_DF_IMAGE_U8);


  int64 e = getTickCount();
  int iter = 100;
  float sum = 0.0;



  e = getTickCount();
  iter = 100;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < iter; i ++)
  {
    /* RESIZEZ OPERATION */
    if(vxuHalfScaleGaussian(context,image,half_image,3) != VX_SUCCESS)
    {
      cout <<"ERROR :"<<"failed to perform scaling"<<endl;
    }

    if(vxuHalfScaleGaussian(context,half_image,half_image_2,3) != VX_SUCCESS)
    {
      cout <<"ERROR :"<<"failed to perform scaling"<<endl;
    }

    if(vxuHalfScaleGaussian(context,half_image_2,half_image_3,3) != VX_SUCCESS)
    {
      cout <<"ERROR :"<<"failed to perform scaling"<<endl;
    }

    if(vxuHalfScaleGaussian(context,half_image_3,half_image_4,3) != VX_SUCCESS)
    {
      cout <<"ERROR :"<<"failed to perform scaling"<<endl;
    }


    sum += (getTickCount() - e) / getTickFrequency();  
  }

  cout <<"Resize to half " <<sum/iter<<endl;

  createMatFromImage(half_image_4,half_dstMat);

  imwrite("RES.jpg",half_dstMat);
  /* Tidy up. */
  vxReleaseImage(&dx);
  vxReleaseImage(&dy);
  vxReleaseImage(&mag);
  vxReleaseContext(&context);
}



vx_image createImageFromMat(vx_context& context, cv::Mat& mat)
{
    vx_imagepatch_addressing_t src_addr = {
        mat.cols, mat.rows, sizeof(vx_uint8), mat.cols * sizeof(vx_uint8), VX_SCALE_UNITY, VX_SCALE_UNITY, 1, 1 };
    void* src_ptr = mat.data;

    vx_image image = vxCreateImageFromHandle(context, VX_DF_IMAGE_U8, &src_addr, &src_ptr, VX_IMPORT_TYPE_HOST);

    return image;
}


vx_status createMatFromImage(vx_image& image, cv::Mat& mat)
{
    vx_status status = VX_SUCCESS;
    vx_uint8 *ptr = NULL;

    cout <<"Creating image "<<mat.cols << " " <<mat.rows <<endl;
    vx_rectangle_t rect;
    vxGetValidRegionImage(image, &rect);
    vx_imagepatch_addressing_t addr = {
        mat.cols, mat.rows, sizeof(vx_uint8), mat.cols * sizeof(vx_uint8), VX_SCALE_UNITY, VX_SCALE_UNITY, 1, 1 };

    status = vxAccessImagePatch(image, &rect, 0, &addr, (void **)&ptr, VX_READ_ONLY);
    mat.data = ptr;

    return status;
}
```

takes 11.1 ms on single execution, and 96ms on average for 100 iterations.

If this is generally true, then what does visionWorks offer ?

I am running "cuda-repo-l4t-r21.3-6-5-local_6.5-50" version of L4T on Jetson TK1

Comment: Please provide full code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @jet47 please check updated question. I have added the full code

Answer (score 2):

You've made a mistake in VisionWorks code. You start timer only once `e = getTickCount();` right before the loop, but you need to start it on each iteration.

```
iter = 100;
for(int i = 0 ; i < iter; i ++)
{
    // START TIMER
    e = getTickCount();

    /* RESIZEZ OPERATION */
    if(vxuHalfScaleGaussian(context,image,half_image,3) != VX_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout <<"ERROR :"<<"failed to perform scaling"<<endl;
    }

    if(vxuHalfScaleGaussian(context,half_image,half_image_2,3) != VX_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout <<"ERROR :"<<"failed to perform scaling"<<endl;
    }

    if(vxuHalfScaleGaussian(context,half_image_2,half_image_3,3) != VX_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout <<"ERROR :"<<"failed to perform scaling"<<endl;
    }

    if(vxuHalfScaleGaussian(context,half_image_3,half_image_4,3) != VX_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout <<"ERROR :"<<"failed to perform scaling"<<endl;
    }

    // STOP TIMER
    sum += (getTickCount() - e) / getTickFrequency();  
}
```

Comment: although it fixed the problem. still the Gpu module for opencv works faster than visionWorks. The above implementation constructs gaussian pyr on RGB image using opencv GpuMat whereas only single channel image on visionworks. Because visionworks HalfScaleGaussian doesnt work for 3 channels.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the following code is mistake.

```
  Mat cv_src1 = imread("br1.png", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
  int width = 1280;
  int height = 720;
```

I think that you should be set as follows.

```
  Mat cv_src1 = imread("br1.png", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
  vx_uint32 width  = cv_src1.cols;
  vx_uint32 height = cv_src1.rows;
```

And, I made sample code to reproduce.
But, VisionWorks(about 0.3ms) faster than GpuMat(about 0.4ms) on my environment.

https://gist.github.com/atinfinity/9c8c067db739b190ba17f2bd8dbe75d6
https://gist.github.com/atinfinity/e8c2f2da6486be51881e3924c13a311c

My environment is as follows.

- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 680
- OS: Windows 10 Pro 64bit
- Compiler: Visual Studio 2013 Update5
- VisionWorks：NVIDIA VisionWorks v1.0.25
- OpenCV: OpenCV 3.1

Comment: well I am running a jetson TK1 with Linux for Tegra. I have found that vision works is just a "tad" bit faster on some kernels but in general opencv gpu module performs faster. Do your findings comply with mine ?

Comment: I think that target function(pyrDown vs vxuHalfScaleGaussian) is same.
But, I understood there is difference(Platform, GPU, OpenCV version, CUDA version etc...).So, could you please try my sample code on your environment, if you possible? Because, I added error-check macro to OpenVX code.

Comment: A couple of things. you are using Opencv 3. I am using Opencv 2.4 (packaged with linux 4 tegra). So my pyrdown is under gpu module. Not under cuda module . I am not sure if there were any modifications to pyrdown from 2.4 to 3.0. You opencv code runs at 4.4ms (avg) , VisionWorks runs at 2.5 (avg). But again, for pyrdown my findings are the same as your code. But not true for all operations.

Comment: e-g the basic operation of multiply when performed on Opencv gpu module in same sized images (1280x720 greyscale) takes 0.6ms to 2ms (varies) . Whereas on vxuMultiply the same operation on same data take consistently 3ms. thats wayyyy too slow for any optimization opportunity on basic kernels.

Comment: Please provide your code. And, why do you think that VisionWorks is faster than GpuMat in all basic kernels? I made sample code to reproduce.As a result, VisionWorks(about 0.11ms) is slightly faster than GpuMat(about 0.13ms) on my environment.
https://gist.github.com/atinfinity/fb3744d581bfd3b578c9a4b01c455615 
https://gist.github.com/atinfinity/6de41febaf8a0f1d29f4455d069dc9f4

Comment: Here are mine .https://github.com/Ideasrefined/jetson_play_area/blob/master/git_opencv_pyrdown.cpp 
https://github.com/Ideasrefined/jetson_play_area/blob/master/git_vxworks_pyrdown.cpp

Comment: even with your codes I am still geting Gpumat faster than visionworks 0.6ms for GpuMat and >= 1ms for VisionWorks

Comment: Thank you for sharing the information. OpenCV is OSS. But, VisionWorks is black box. So, it is difficult to understand the difference of internal processing. You might be able to investigate the behaviour of GPU using Nsight.

Comment: Hey @dandelion1124 how were you able to run visionworks with opencv 3.1, I am trying to run visionworks `opencv_npp_interop` sample with opencv version 3.3 but I am getting error `undefined reference  to cv::String::deallocate()`