# Feeding a new cv::Mat into a vx_graph

Tags: c++, opencv, openvx

Given sample code like [in this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36544717/1270789) (error checking deleted for brevity):

```
vx_image inputImage = vxCreateImage( graph, width, height, VX_DF_IMAGE_S16 );
vx_image outputImage = vxCreateImage( graph, width, height, VX_DF_IMAGE_S16 );
vx_graph graph = vxCreateGraph( context );
vx_image intermediate1 = vxCreateVirtualImage( graph, width, height, VX_DF_IMAGE_S16 );
vx_image intermediate2 = vxCreateVirtualImage( graph, width, height, VX_DF_IMAGE_S16 );
vx_image intermediate3 = vxCreateVirtualImage( graph, width, height, VX_DF_IMAGE_S16 );

vxSobel3x3Node(graph,inputImage,intermediate1,intermediate2);
vxMagnitudeNode(graph,intermediate1,intermediate2,intermediate3);
vxConvertDepthNode(graph,intermediate3,outputImage,VX_CONVERT_POLICY_WRAP,0);    

vxVerifyGraph( graph );

vxProcessGraph( graph );
```

And the classic OpenCV reading video loop:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap;
cap.open("/Testing/test.avi");
for(;;)
{
    cv::Mat frame;
    cap >> frame;
    if( frame.empty() ) break;
    // TODO: what goes here?
    vxProcessGraph( graph );
}
```

How do I get the `frame` into the `inputImage` so I can call `vxProcessGraph()` correctly? I know that:

```
vx_image image = nvx_cv::createVXImageFromCVMat(frame);
```

Is a helper for getting a `vx_image`, but I cannot seem to find an example of what to do next. Some NVidia documentation I read suggested:

```
vxAccessImagePatch(...);
// copy pixel-by-pixel??
vxCommitImagePatch(...);
```

However, this seems a bit too brute-force-like, so is there some nicer way (`vxSetParameter`, perhaps, but the documentation is very unclear) to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to work out the solution, as what was confusing me about examples was the use of a [helper function](https://github.com/hakanardo/openvx_sample/blob/master/helper/vx_helper.c#L405) not in the official API.

```
vx_status vxAddParameterToGraphByIndex(vx_graph g, vx_node n, vx_uint32 index)
{
    vx_parameter p = vxGetParameterByIndex(n, index);
    vx_status status = vxAddParameterToGraph(g, p);
    vxReleaseParameter(&p);
    return status;
}
```

Now, my sample code above needs a quick modification:

```
vx_node sobel = vxSobel3x3Node(graph,inputImage,intermediate1,intermediate2);
```

Then the magic line of:

```
vxAddParameterToGraphByIndex(graph, sobel, 0);
```

The `0` here means the 0th parameter to the `sobel` node, excluding the `graph` itself.

Next, my loop becomes:

```
if( frame.empty() ) break;
vx_image image = nvx_cv::createVXImageFromCVMat(frame);
vxSetGraphParameterByIndex(graph, 0, (vx_reference) image);
vxProcessGraph( graph );
vxReleaseImage(&image);
```

Here, the 0 means the 0th parameter that we have added to the graph. If I had access the `vx_parameter p` above, there is the slightly less unfriendly:

```
vxSetParameterByIndex(p, (vx_reference) image);
```

This might work on its own, but I don't know if there's extra work to do to notify the `vx_graph` of the change.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to create a `vx_image` which only references the data stored in a `cv::Mat`.  Something using the `vx_image` to access data would end up actually accessing the data stored in the `Mat`.  This approach uses only documented OpenCV and [OpenVX](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenVX/specs/1.0/html/df/d09/group__group__image.html#gadb03cc69dc197b55a3e1981311e776ac) functions.  From this [Intel documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/sample-auto-contrast-using-opencv-to-create-openvx-input-from-image-file):

```
vx_image get_vx_image_from_Mat(vx_context graph, cv::Mat &mat) {
    vx_imagepatch_addressing_t frame_format {};
    frame_format.dim_x = mat.cols;
    frame_format.dim_y = mat.rows;
    return vxCreateImageFromHandle(graph, 
                                   VX_DF_IMAGE_S16, 
                                   &format, 
                                   &((void*)mat.data),
                                   VX_IMPORT_TYPE_HOST);
}
```

Presumably, the `cv:Mat` needs to survive at least as long as any `vx_image` that is created in this manner.